# map not rendering content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactjs-native

I have no idea, the map does not render, but the console.log is working.

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
`return (
      <div>
        {this.state.officeHours.map((value, index) => {
          console.log("value", value.description);
          return
            (
              <FormGroup row key={index}>
                <Col sm={12}>
                  <Row>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                          <IntlMessages id={value.description} />
                        </Col>

                        <Col sm={6}>
                        </Col>

                      </Row>
                    </Col>
                <Col sm={2}>
                  <Row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                      <InputSelect
                        options={[]}
                      />
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={6}>
                      <InputSelect

                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Col>

                <Col sm={2}>
                  <IntlMessages id="label.secondRound" />
                </Col>


                <Col sm={2}>
                  <IntlMessages id="label.thirdRound" />
                </Col>


                <Col sm={2}>
                  <IntlMessages id="label.fourthRound" />
                </Col>
              </Row>

            </Col>

          </FormGroup>
        )

    })}

  </div>
);`
```

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: Its because alone `return` will be treated as `return ;` means nothing will return so either use `return (` (brace should be in the same line) or `return <FormGroup ....`